# Enumerate inside a theorem environment

Tags: lists, numbering, theorems, enumerate, enumitem

I use the `enumitem` package:

```
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
```

And I put some numeration like this in a theorem environment with `\theoremstyle{plain}`:

```
\begin{prop}
    We have
        \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
            \item $χ(c_M)=-\Id_{σM}$,

        and if $π_0(M)=0$, 
            \item $χ(f_M)=-α_M^{-1}$.
        \end{enumerate}
\end{prop}
```

the `[(i)]` after `\begin{enumerate}` is supposed to make items indexed by `(i)(ii)(iii)`. But in this theorem environment, as texts are italic, the `(i)(ii)(iii)` become funny things like *(i)(ii)(iii)*. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the short labels method, you should specify the label with the key-value syntax that `enumitem` provides:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label={\upshape(\roman*)}]
```

Comment: Thanks. I did a global replacement of `\begin{enumerate}[(i)]`. Is there a way to make a short hand for this? typing that long string every time is a bit painful.

Comment: BTW, what should I replace `\begin{enumerate}[a)]` with?

Comment: OK I put `[label=\upshape{\alph*)}]` there.

Comment: @hyh Your braces are in the wrong place: this should be `label={\upshape\alph*)}`  `\upshape` does not take an argument.

Comment: I use the function *search* and *replacement* of the EDITOR program to change quickly something like that if I already wrote wrong code and repeated in several places.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the following:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label={\upshape(\roman*)}, align=left, widest=iii, leftmargin=*]
```

to get left-aligned roman (i), (ii), (iii), with no leftmargin, and the widest spacing taken to be (iii).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to repeat theses options for every Theorem/Proposition/etc in your article, you can make the following global choice at the preamble:

```
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\upshape(\roman*)}}
```