# How to make the numbering of items non-italic in a theorem environment

Tags: amsmath, enumerate, theorems, itemize, italic

Is there a way to make the numbering of items non italic. To to be specific in the following example I would like that (v) becomes non italic (italic blablabla is fine).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}


\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item[(v)] blablabla
  \end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item[(v)] blablabla
  \end{itemize}
\end{thm}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Use enumitem to control all lists. You can make the default label for enumerate upright. Also you should not be numbering items manually, again learn to use enumitem, it will make life a lot easier. If you are adamant that this should only hit theorem, you can use features from the etoolbox package to add enumitem configurations to all theorem envs

Comment: Thank you, as explained in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100521/enumerate-inside-a-theorem-environment using `\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{label={\upshape(\roman*)}}` one can enumerate upright. Unfortunately in this circumstance, I should enumerate manually.

Comment: Please explain why manual?

Comment: In my situation I would like to have `Theorem 1. item 1 item 2`, `Theorem 2 item 3 item 4 item 5` etc.

Comment: You can use
\begin{enumerate}[label = \emph{\arabic*)}]

Answer (score 5):

You can use  the `start` key of `enumitem` or, better, the `series` key which makes all enumerate environments in a series to have the same layout and share the same counter.  Here  I use a `thmenum` series. Note you may have as many series as you please.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}%
 \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{thm}{\setlist[enumerate, 1]{font=\upshape, nosep,  wide=0.5em, before=\leavevmode}}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
  \begin{enumerate}[series=thmenum]
  \item Blablabla
  \item Bliblibli
  \end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
  \begin{enumerate}[thmenum]
  \item Blablabla
  \item Bliblibli
  \item Blobloblo
  \end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The most funny part was `Blablabla, Bliblibli, Blobloblo`. :)